# MS Teams Bot - How to return a paginated list?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am developing a teams bot using Bot Framework SDK 4 in C#, I want to return a list of profiles with pagination, similar to Customer Insights Bot, screenshots below

[image]

[image]

Comment: Kiran, it looks like you're still quite new to posting questions, so have a look at the guidelines on this site, but in short: please state your question more specifically, and show what you've tried so far. Your question is likely going to get downvoted and closed very soon by moderators as it is right now...

Comment: @Kiran, If you are looking out for pagination of search results for a query, check default query structure and response card types of Messaging extension search command. For more information, check [Respond to the search command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/search-commands/respond-to-search?tabs=dotnet)